# Finding HWID in C

Tags: c, windows

Is there any way to find a unique hardware ID to a computer in C?

(Windows)

Comment: Do not put [tags] in the subject line. That is what the tags field is for.  (editing your subject line...)

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  It isn't possible to uniquely and 100% reliably to identify a machine, but if you could give us some insight on what you are trying to accomplish, perhaps we could make a realistic suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source code [here](http://skilinium.com/blog/downloads/Win32HWID.CPP) helped me accomplish what I wanted.

Thanks for the initial help guys.

Answer (score 0):

How exactly would you define the "computer"?

The CPU?  What about the same CPU in a different MoBo?
The MoBo?  What if it gets a new BIOS? a new CPU?
The graphics card?  What if the machine has more than 1 GPU? and it gets upgraded?

Once you define exactly what you're asking, you'll be much closer to an answer

Comment: Anything unique to the computer itself. Motherboard would most likely be the best.

Answer (score 0):

Ethernet MAC address is a common choice.

But be careful:

a) there can be more than one

b) they can be added or removed - or moved between computers

c) often the MAC for a given card can be over-ridden by software

d) virtual network adapters (like for VMWare, VirtualBox, etc) are cheap (no hardware!) and have configurable MACs